# как сделать рассылку по часовому поясу telegram бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Есть вот такая функция

```
# Функция отправка книг
def send_message1():
# получаем айди юзеров
users = functions.select1_book()
# путь до книг
file = open(r'/home/roman/Desktop/urist_part_2/book/'+ random.choice(os.listdir("book")),"rb")
for row in users:
    # отправляем всем юзерам из базы данных книгу          
    bot.send_document(row[0], file, caption ='Новая книга')

# выбираем из базы данных таймзону пользователей и по ней делаем рассылку
schedule.every().day.at("8:00","Europe/Moscow").do(send_message1)
```

У меня в базе есть айди пользователей, которым нужно делать рассылку и их таймзоны к примеру "Europe/Moscow" "Europe/Amsterdam"

Я не понимаю, каким образом можно совершить рассылку, чтобы из базы данных брались таймзоны пользователей проходились по  schedule.every().day.at("8:00",f"{timezone}").do(send_message1) и чтобы они были привязаны к юзерам и всем юзерам корректно отправлялись сообщения в соответствии с их таймзоной

Comment: В БД к каждому id добавь номер часового пояса, потом сделай условие, что если id, допустим, 1 ( он заменяет "Europe/Moscow"), то всем пользователям с данным номером отправляется рассылка в определенное время. Я бы отталкивался от одного времени, то есть в Амстердаме на 2 часа меньше, чем в МСК, значит для пользователей с номером 2 ( "Europe/Amsterdam") будет высылаться в такое-то московское время, то есть на два часа позже

Comment: таймзоны могут быть абсолютно рандомные, и писать все таймзоны не очень прикольно

Comment: всего существует 24 таймзоны. Тут придется значит просто скопировать код 23 раза. Да, получиться много строчек, но это лишь тот вариант, как это реализовал бы я. Возможно не совсем корректно, но думаю работать должно. Так же указать не совсем каждое местное время, а отталкиваться от одного города. Например МСК или Амстердама. Вы лишь скажите выбрать либо свой регион, либо тот, чье время такое же, как и в представленных городах